# File System Update, Locking, Timing Issues

Tags: java, windows, file-locking

Using Java's java.nio.channels.FileLock I am trying to synchronize file reading and writing on a Windows filesystem.  I have a test program that runs in a loop:

1. Lock the file X.LOCK
2. Test that X.JSON exists (just a consistency check)
3. Write the file X.TMP
4. Rename X.TMP to X.JSON using java.nio.files.Files.move() deletes the old X.JSON and renames X.TMP to X.JSON in a atomic action.
5. Test that X.JSON exists (this always returns true)
6. Release the lock on X.LOCK

I run this in a tight loop in multiple instances of the test program.  It locks the symbolic file "X.LOCK" and not the actual file that is being written and renamed.  I believe that is necessary to preserve the lock through the rename operation.

Here is what I find:  In about 2% of the cases, process 1 will write/rename/release the lock, and process 2 which was waiting on that lock will get that lock, start executing, but find that **X.JSON does not exist**.   The "exists" check returns false!

If I introduce a delay (200ms) after the rename, and before the unlock, then the whole thing runs 100% reliably.  I can try smaller delays, but I am loath to add any delay since that is never the right answer to making a reliable program.

It appears that when one process atomically renames a file, it takes some time for the other process to see that.  But the unlock signal goes faster!  So the lock signal tells the other program to move forward, and that other program can't see the file it is supposed to be working on!

Question: is there any way I can force the unlock signal to be sent AFTER the file system has settled and guaranteed to be consistent with operations that were put in there before the unlock was called?

Any hints on where I can look for information on this kind of timing/sequencing on a Windows file system using Java?  I have not tried this test program on any other platform yet, but I certainly will check Linux soon.

## UPDATE

I am suspicious of interference from virus scanning.  It got a test to a reproducible state, and it was failing about 1% of the time, this time reporting "AccessDeniedException".  I think the virus scan might be kicking in, scanning the file between being created and being renamed, and when it does this, it runs at a higher privilege, and causes this error when trying to rename it.  Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I am working on that.  This problem is timing dependent, and so when I move the code around it sometimes disappears.   Making the code "minimal" is the issue.  But posting the entire million lines is not possible either.

Answer (score 1):

The solution appears to be that on a system where virus scan is running, depending upon the specific brand of virus scanner, it is possible that the call to move can be interfered with.  I was calling:

```
java.nio.files.Files.move(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, 
           StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE );
```

This command will effectively delete the `dest` if it exists, and rename the `src` file to the `dest`, and it will do it atomically.  It is documented that if it can not do it atomically, it will throw an exception.  I was getting  `AccessDeniedException` which is not mentioned in the documentation specifically but apparently happens.

What appears to be happening is that -- and this all depended on a specific timing that was happening about 1% of the time -- was that the operation of the virus scan either on the `src` file or the `dest` file caused the atomic move to fail.

I tried on each of three different systems configured differently.  The windows computer with the Microsoft Windows Defender never caused the `AccessDeniedException` while another with Trend Micro virus scan was failing regularly.  That is not a thorough survey of virus scan options; they were the only options I had available for test.  The machine with the Trend Micro also has an encrypted hard disk, and that might be a factor to make the timing such as to trip this problem.

I even went so far as to implement a "retry" where if the move threw an exception, the code would wait 10ms and try again.  Even with this, the retry failed about 0.1% of the time.  Maybe I could have waited longer, but that would in any case be a problem making the code slower.

What worked was to add a step to delete the file being replaced before doing the move.  My guess is that the virus scan is either stopped by the delete, or else it continues to scan on the `src` or `dest` file without bothering the `move` command.  The steps are these:

1. Lock the file X.LOCK
2. Test that X.JSON exists (just a consistency check)
3. Write the file X.TMP
4. **(NEW)** Delete the old X.JSON
5. Rename X.TMP to X.JSON using java.nio.files.Files.move() simply renames X.TMP to X.JSON in an atomic action.
6. Test that X.JSON exists (this always returns true)
7. Release the lock on X.LOCK

Is this now 100% reliable?  I can't say for sure, since all this is timing dependent.  It is possible that this just changed the timing in a way that allows it to run.